# Find Fourier series of $\cosh(ax)$

Tags: fourier-series

> Prove that in the range $-\pi < x < \pi$, 
>   $$\cosh(ax) = \frac{2a^2  \sinh(a \pi)}{\pi} \left(\frac1{2a^2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{1}{n^2 + a^2}\cos (nx) \right)
> $$

Now, I have tried to get the Fourier series of $\cosh(ax)$.
I got 
$$
a_0 = 2\frac{\sinh(a \pi)}{\pi a}\\ 
a_n = - \frac{2a\sinh(a \pi)}{\pi(n^2 - a^2)}
$$
Probably I got 
$$
f(x) = \frac{\sinh(a \pi)}{\pi} \left( \frac1a- 2a \sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^n \frac1{n^2 - a^2}  \cos nx}\right)
$$
I tried twice and again I got this answer which is not matching with the question. 
Please tell me what is my fault and how to solve this?

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackexchange! Please use the [formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial!

Comment: I think the formula in the yellow box is wrong, I'm using Introduction To Calculus And Analysis by Courant & John and it's actually $\dfrac{2a}{\pi}$ in the front. They might have gotten it wrong , though. There's a couple typos in the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cosh(ax)\cos(nx)\,dx&=2\text{Re}\left(\int_0^\pi \cosh(ax)\,e^{inx}
\,dx\right)\\\\
&= \text{Re}\left(\int_0^\pi \left(e^{(a+in)x}+e^{-(a-in)x}\right)\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left((-1)^n\left(\frac{e^{a\pi}}{a+in}-\frac{e^{-a\pi}}{a-in}\right)\right)\\\\
&=(-1)^n\,\frac{2a\sinh(a\pi)}{a^2+n^2}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I've got. The answer matches the required solution, except that it's 2a and not 2a^2.
[image]

Comment: I'm confused. Are you posting this to check your solution? In that case, please post a new question. If you want to give another answer, please type it in MathJax to make it easier to read.